# pthread_kill SIGUSR1 received as SIGBUS

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, signals, posix

I try to wait for **SIGUSR1** in a thread. Everything seems to work fine but the signal received after `sigwait` is **SIGBUS** instead of **SIGUSR1**.

I don't know why. Any advice?

[Check it out online.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gmlnYFTJdu8rPicG)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* thread(void* arg) {
    sigset_t mask, oldmask;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    if (sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1) != 0) {
        perror("sigaddset");
        exit(1);
    }

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

    int sig{};
    auto ret = sigwait(&mask, &sig);

    // Sig is SIGBUS (10).
    printf("Signal: %d, Ret %d\n", sig, ret);

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid;

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        exit(1);
    }

    sleep(1);

    pthread_kill(tid, SIGUSR1);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I am aware of the existence of condition variables.

Comment: How do you know you get `SIGBUS`? What is the output you get from the program? What is the output you expected?

Comment: Why do you block signal first?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - the variable sig is 10

Comment: @VTT - without this, I don't get a signal at all -- please try it out online

Comment: According to [this Linux signal manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) the signal value `10` is for `SIGUSR1`. So you're program is correct. Signal numbers aren't fixed or officially specified, they depend on operating system.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude said, that seems to be correct. Try to use `strsignal(sig)` to get the signal name and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: What are the curly braces suppose to do here: `int sig{};`?

Comment: @alk: That’s a C++ idiom which roughly means “initialize as empty” (here, just 0, but some choose to use it for consistency with more complicated types).